# Disable the default keyvalue pipe sort in angular

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

```
<tr *ngFor="let a of arrayOfObjects">
    <td *ngFor="let item of cfValues | keyvalue">
        {{item.value}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am just trying to print the items in the regular order but the key/value pipe does a default sorting based on the index.
Is there a way to disable the default sorting?

Comment: Default sorting? IMK, it depends on the browsers on how they pull out the keys, JS objects are unordered.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to return 0 if you want them to not be ordered.
So in your cause you could either do
`<td *ngFor="let item of cfValues | keyvalue : 0">`

But that would throw a ts error: `TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined`

Else, you can create a function that returns 0 and use

```js
returnZero() {
    return 0
}
```

[... in your template]

```html
<td *ngFor="let item of cfValues | keyvalue : returnZero">
```

Comment: If you're using typescript, the function should be like: `returnZero() {
    return 0;
    } `